# Criar chave no registro do windows sem permissão em c#

Tags: c#, windows

Minha aplicação precisa se inserir nas exclusões do Windows Defender. Bastaria criar uma chave MYapp.exe no caminho 
`{HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Processes}`, porém é me retornando a mensagem informando que não possuo permissão.

Sou usuário administrador da máquina e minha aplicação está sendo executada como administrador mas o erro é o mesmo.

O windows 8.1 e 10 possuem um comando próprio para isso que pode ser executado pelo Power Shell, porém o Windows 7 não. Podem me ajudar?

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
RegistryKey localRaiz;
RegistryKey key;

try
{
    string path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Exclusions\Processes";
    localRaiz = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

    key = localRaiz.OpenSubKey(path);
    key.SetValue("MPI.exe", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    key.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que abrir a chave no modo `"writable"`, para isto basta alterar

```
key = localRaiz.OpenSubKey(path);
```

para

```
key = localRaiz.OpenSubKey(path, true);
```

Referência: [Método RegistryKey.OpenSubKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: já tinha tentado dessa forma. Desse jeito o visual studio me retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro: "Acesso ao Registro solicitado não é permitido". Lembrando que sou administrador da máquina e minha aplicação é executado como administrador.

Answer (score 1):

Execute o VS como administrador e sua aplicação como administrador

```
public static  bool GravarRegistroUsersSoftware(string Subchave, string nomevalor, string valor)
{
   try
   {
       // cria uma referêcnia para a chave de registro Software
       RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(".DEFAULT\\Software", true);

       // cria um Subchave como o nome GravaRegistro
       rk = rk.CreateSubKey(Subchave);

       // grava o caminho na SubChave GravaRegistro
       rk.SetValue(nomevalor, valor);

       // fecha a Chave de Restistro registro
       rk.Close();

       return true;
   }

   catch (Exception except)
   {
       UltimoErro = except.Message;
       return false;
   }
}

public static  string LerRegistroUsersSoftware(string Subchave, string nomevalor)
{
   try
   {
       string tmpstr = null;
       // cria uma referêcnia para a chave de registro Software
       RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(".DEFAULT\\Software", true);

       // realiza a leitura do registro
       tmpstr = rk.OpenSubKey(Subchave, true).GetValue(nomevalor).ToString();
       return tmpstr;
   }

   catch (Exception except)
   {
       UltimoErro = except.Message;
       return null;
   }
}
```